# Developing Offline chrome application with JSF

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, jakarta-ee, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Can you please direct me to a reference on developing offline chrome application with Java Server Faces?

Comment: JSF is a server technology.  That doesn't make any sense.  You need Javascript.

Comment: Agreed. A bunch of preloaded data, single page and a lot of JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. That is not possible it seems. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into Chrome Packaged Apps? It is a new platform, focused on offline and out-of-the-browser app development using web technologies (HTML5, JavaScript and CSS).  See more in http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) and [skuntsel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820286/skuntsel) in the comments, that does not make any sense. JSF is a server side technology and client side application is needed to be developed with JavaScript.

There are many technologies to pick from as extracted by [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/launching)

HTML5 - the family of HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript technologies powering the modern web.

Native Client - run your native C/C++ code in the browser’s sandbox! Get started with the Native Client SDK.

Adobe Flash - probably the most widely distributed browser plug-in.

A mix - mix and match these technologies as best as you see fit.